# Does the subset of a power set include the generating set of the power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *Probability Essentials* by Jacod and Protter, second edition, page 7:

> Let $\Omega$ be an abstract space, that is with no special structure. Let $2^{\Omega}$ denote all subsets of $\Omega$, including the empty set denoted by $\emptyset$. With $\mathcal{A}$ being a subset of $2^{\Omega}$, we consider the following properties:
>
> 1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$.

For an arbitrary subset $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^\Omega$, how is it possible that $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$? Is it possible that the authors meant to write $\Omega \in 2^\Omega$?

Here is a counterexample to clarify my confusion:

Assume $\Omega = \{0, 1\}$. Then $2^\Omega = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0, 1\}\}$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ can be any subset of $2^\Omega$, let $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset\}$. Then $\Omega \notin \mathcal{A}$.

Is what the authors wrote correct, and my confusion is due to misunderstanding definitions, or is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just "considering" the property 1, which may be satisfied by certain subsets $\mathcal{A}$ of $2^\Omega$, and not satisfied by others.  They are certainly not claiming that every subset has property 1, and as you say, there are obvious counterexamples.

Later in the text, they will be particularly interested in those subsets which do satisfy property 1 (and probably other properties as well).

Answer (score 1):

What the author wrote is correct. These are merely properties that any particular subset of $2^\Omega$ may or may not possess. They are not asserting that these are true for all $\mathcal{A}$.